# Helix along vector in 3D space

Tags: vectors, euclidean-geometry, 3d

Let's say I have a random vector, for example <1, 3, 5>.

What would the function be for a helix that spirals around/along this vector with a given radius?

Comment: A helix with radius $r$ about the $x$ axis is of the form $\langle ct, r \cos t, r \sin t \rangle$. Apply a rotation matrix to this vector, sending $\langle 1,0,0 \rangle$ to $\langle 1, 3, 5 \rangle$.

Comment: Why not start from (0,0,0)? The challenge is to calculate c and r. For a given t, for the helix ending at (1,3,5). Is it clear?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let $\mathbf{W}$ be a unit vector in the direction of the given vector. So, in your case $\mathbf{W} = (1,3,5)/\sqrt{35}$. Let $\mathbf{U}$ and $\mathbf{V}$ be two other unit vectors perpendicular to $\mathbf{W}$ and to each other, so that $\mathbf{U}$, $\mathbf{V}$, $\mathbf{W}$ form a mutually orthogonal set. In less fancy language, $\mathbf{U}$, $\mathbf{V}$, $\mathbf{W}$ form a coordinate frame. Constructing $\mathbf{U}$ and $\mathbf{V}$ is not very difficult. One approach is to let $\mathbf{U}$ be the unit vector in the direction of $\mathbf{W} \times (1,0,0)$, and then let $\mathbf{V} = \mathbf{W} \times \mathbf{U}$.

Suppose we want a helix with radius $a$ and pitch $b/a$. We can get this by rotating the [standard equation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Helix) to the $UVW$ coordinate system.
The standard equation is:
$$
P(t) = (a\cos t, a \sin t , bt)
= (a\cos t)\mathbf{I} + (a \sin t)\mathbf{J}  + (bt)\mathbf{K}
$$
The rotated equation is
$$
P(t) = (a\cos t)\mathbf{U} + (a \sin t)\mathbf{V}  + (bt)\mathbf{W}
$$